# Tridion 2011 Icons and how to set them to be used

Tags: gui-extensions

What links an icon to a specific Tridion object such as a schema, folder, TBB? I am seeing the following  context in the url for icon images;

WebUI/Editors/CME/Themes/Carbon/icon_v6.1.0.55920.37_.png?name=T2L0P0&size=16

Where is this controlled? I look in the carbon folder and do not see these images. I do however see images in the ebUI\Editors\CME\Themes\Carbon\Images\Icons

What is assigning the icon_v6.1.0.55920.37_.png?name=T2L0P0&size=16 part of the URL?

Answer (score 9):

Basically it is managed in an HTTP module that is configured in the WebUI\Web.config file.

```
<add type="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Http.IconUrlRewriter, Tridion.Web.UI.Core" name="CME-Core-IconUrlRewriter"/>
```

The icons that you see for instance T2L0P0 is a virtual name that is translated to a valid image.

- T: Type
- L: Lock
- P: Published

It is the way the CME manages different icons of an item, it also support different sizes, in this case you are trying to get the 16x16 folder icon.

Images are located here.

```
[TRIDION_HOME]\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Themes\Carbon\Images
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As an additional note, the _v6.1.0.55920.37_ refers to the version - the last number coming from the modified version in the system config file (used to flush caching proper).

Answer (score 4):

Check out Serguei Martchenko's [Template Building Block Type Indicator eXtension](http://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/template-building-block-type-indicator-extension/661/) as an example to extend icons.

His config includes a match for TBBs which maps to specifically named icons in a separate "themes" folder:

```
<ext:itemicons>
  <icon match="^T2048L[01]P0S[1-7]$" path="${theme}Images/${icon}.${size}x${size}.png" />
</ext:itemicons>
```

Depending on your use case, it's probably better to add custom scenarios as an extension, which will make managing this easier across CMS environments and especially for upgrades.